# Python - Delete duplicates in a dataframe based on two columns combinations?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns in Python:

```
Name1 Name2 Value
Juan  Ale   1
Ale   Juan  1
```

and would like to eliminate the duplicates based on columns Name1 and Name2 combinations.

In my example both rows are equal (but they are in different order), and I would like to delete the second row and just keep the first one, so the end result should be:

```
Name1 Name2 Value
Juan  Ale   1
```

Any idea will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can convert to `frozenset` and use [`pd.DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html).

```
res = df[~df[['Name1', 'Name2']].apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]

print(res)

  Name1 Name2  Value
0  Juan   Ale      1
```

`frozenset` is necessary instead of `set` since `duplicated` uses hashing to check for duplicates.

Scales better with columns than rows. For a large number of rows, use @Wen's sort-based algorithm.

Answer (score 28):

By using `np.sort` with `duplicated`

```
df[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['Name1','Name2']].values,1)).duplicated()]
Out[614]: 
  Name1 Name2  Value
1   Ale  Juan      1
```

Performance

```
df=pd.concat([df]*100000)

%timeit df[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['Name1','Name2']].values,1)).duplicated()]
10 loops, best of 3: 69.3 ms per loop
%timeit df[~df[['Name1', 'Name2']].apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]
1 loop, best of 3: 3.72 s per loop
```

Comment: This is 100 times better than the frozenset method.

Comment: @coldspeed Yep , even the sort is match fast , I still keep your suggestion in mind, `apply` is less efficient. :-)

Comment: Thanks! It's super quick!
I had to make a small change, since it was raising:  
  
 `'IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)'` but this did the trick:  
   
`df[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['Name1','Name2']].values,1)).duplicated().values]`

Answer (score 7):

*Know Im kinda late for this question but giving my contribution anyway :)*

You can also use `get_dummies` and `add` for a good way of creating hashable rows

```
df[~(pd.get_dummies(df.a).add(pd.get_dummies(df.b), fill_value=0)).duplicated()]
```

Times are not as good as @Wen's answer, but it isstill way faster than `apply`+`frozen_set`

```
df=pd.concat([df]*1000000)
%timeit df[~(pd.get_dummies(df.a).add(pd.get_dummies(df.b), fill_value=0)).duplicated()]
1.8 s ± 85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['a','b']].values,1)).duplicated()]
1.26 s ± 19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df[~df[['a', 'b']].apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]
1min 9s ± 684 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: interesting.. `get_dummies` for this purpose is very innovative :)