# Create distinct cluster for non-ordered sequences in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, combinations, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe containing "ID"s of persons in the first column. Each person can have up to 3 other persons that it is assigned into a unique group (or cluster) with. The related "CO_ID"s of a person are stored in 3 other columns. If a person is alone, i.e. there are no other persons assigned to it, it should be considered as it is in an one-person cluster anyway, the values of the other columns beeing nan. Same applies for persons who are only assigned to e.g. one other person: In this case one column contains a "CO_ID" while the other two columns beeing nan.

I wonder how I can assign those (through the CO_ID columns already excatly determined) clusters to each ID via an additional column called "CLUSTER"? Is there a prebuild function for this?

As it is obvious to see from the example data provided, the order of the "CO_ID"s is not important (for ID = ID1, it doesn't matter if CO_ID1 = ID2 and CO_ID2 = ID3 or CO_ID1 = ID3 and CO_ID2 = ID2).

The input data df1 looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4','ID5','ID6','ID7','ID8','ID9','ID10'] ,
                    'CO_ID1' : ['ID2','ID1','ID2','ID6','ID8','ID4','ID4','ID5', np.nan, 'ID4'],
                    'CO_ID2' : ['ID3','ID3','ID1', 'ID7', np.nan, 'ID7','ID6',  np.nan, np.nan, 'ID6'],
                    'CO_ID3' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'ID10', np.nan, 'ID10', 'ID10', np.nan, np.nan, 'ID7']})

Out[1]: 

  ID CO_ID1 CO_ID2 CO_ID3 
0   ID1    ID2    ID3    NaN      
1   ID2    ID1    ID3    NaN      
2   ID3    ID2    ID1    NaN      
3   ID4    ID6    ID7   ID10      
4   ID5    ID8    NaN    NaN      
5   ID6    ID4    ID7   ID10      
6   ID7    ID4    ID6   ID10      
7   ID8    ID5    NaN    NaN      
8   ID9    NaN    NaN    NaN      
9  ID10    ID4    ID6    ID7
```

And the desired output data df2 looks like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4','ID5','ID6','ID7','ID8','ID9','ID10'] ,
                    'CO_ID1' : ['ID2','ID1','ID2','ID6','ID8','ID4','ID4','ID5', np.nan, 'ID4'],
                    'CO_ID2' : ['ID3','ID3','ID1', 'ID7', np.nan, 'ID7','ID6',  np.nan, np.nan, 'ID6'],
                    'CO_ID3' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'ID10', np.nan, 'ID10', 'ID10', np.nan, np.nan, 'ID7'],
                    'Cluster' : ['C1','C1','C1','C2','C3','C2','C2','C3','C4','C2']})

Out[2]:

  ID CO_ID1 CO_ID2 CO_ID3 Cluster
0   ID1    ID2    ID3    NaN      C1
1   ID2    ID1    ID3    NaN      C1
2   ID3    ID2    ID1    NaN      C1
3   ID4    ID6    ID7   ID10      C2
4   ID5    ID8    NaN    NaN      C3
5   ID6    ID4    ID7   ID10      C2
6   ID7    ID4    ID6   ID10      C2
7   ID8    ID5    NaN    NaN      C3
8   ID9    NaN    NaN    NaN      C4
9  ID10    ID4    ID6    ID7      C2
```

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your input and output. Should the 3rd row be `ID3 ID2 ID1 NaN`? `ID3` is repeated twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `frozenset` row-wise to create distinct groups which are hashable and ordered (so which row they appear in is irrelevant). Group by these and use `ngroup` to label each distinct group.

```
df1['Cluster'] = 'C'+ (df1.groupby(df1.apply(frozenset, 1), sort=False).ngroup()+1).astype('str')
```

#### Output

```
     ID CO_ID1 CO_ID2 CO_ID3 Cluster
0   ID1    ID2    ID3    NaN      C1
1   ID2    ID1    ID3    NaN      C1
2   ID3    ID2    ID1    NaN      C1
3   ID4    ID6    ID7   ID10      C2
4   ID5    ID8    NaN    NaN      C3
5   ID6    ID4    ID7   ID10      C2
6   ID7    ID4    ID6   ID10      C2
7   ID8    ID5    NaN    NaN      C3
8   ID9    NaN    NaN    NaN      C4
9  ID10    ID4    ID6    ID7      C2
```

---

If performance is an issue, sort with `numpy`. We'll need to replace the floating `NaN` with strings so all values can be compared across columns.

```
import numpy as np

d = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df1.replace(np.NaN, 'NaN').values, 1), index=df1.index)
df1['Cluster'] = 'C'+(d.groupby(d.columns.tolist()).ngroup()+1).astype('str')
```

Comment: Check the running time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182228/python-delete-duplicates-in-a-dataframe-based-on-two-columns-combinations/51182428#51182428