# How to combine connected strings within pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to figure out how to count a given combination of 2 strings regardless of which string is first / second.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = [[('Smith JR', 'Kim YY'), ('Smith JR', 'Ron AA'), ('Kim YY', 'Ron AA')],
          [('Kim YY', 'Smith JR')], [('Smith JR', 'Ron AA')]]

flat_list = [item for sublist in mylist for item in sublist]

df = pd.DataFrame(flat_list, columns=["From", "To"])
df_graph = df.groupby(["From", "To"]).size().reset_index()
df_graph.columns = ["From", "To", "Count"]

print(df_graph)
```

which gives:

```
       From        To  Count
0    Kim YY    Ron AA      1
1    Kim YY    Smith JR    1
2  Smith JR    Kim YY      1
3  Smith JR    Ron AA      2
```

but since Kim YY Smith JR and Smith JR Kim YY form a connection between the same two people I want it to give:

```
       From        To  Count
0    Kim YY    Ron AA      1
1    Kim YY    Smith JR    2
2  Smith JR    Ron AA      2
```

I have seen a number of solutions which remove the duplicated row but don't combine the Counts from each row as I desire.  I can't seem to figure out how to combine the

```
1    Kim YY    Smith JR    1
2  Smith JR    Kim YY      1
```

rows such that only the Kim YY - Smith JR row remains and the Count is 2.  Also, in my actual data the count can be greater than 1 for a given row.

Answer (score 5):

Sort the two columns together before adding to the dataframe so that you are guaranteed that a pair will only appear in a certain order. Only then apply your counting method. Using the method from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182228/python-delete-duplicates-in-a-dataframe-based-on-two-columns-combinations?noredirect=1&lq=1) for sorting:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

mylist = [[('Smith JR','Kim YY'),('Smith JR','Ron AA'),('Kim YY','Ron AA')],[('Kim YY','Smith JR')],[('Smith JR','Ron AA')]]

flat_list = [item for sublist in mylist for item in sublist]

df = pd.DataFrame(flat_list, columns=["From", "To"])
#create a new dataframe with the value pairs sorted. You can also sort earlier if you prefer.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[["From", "To"]]), columns = ["From", "To"])
#now, just apply the groupby.
df_graph = df.groupby(["From", "To"], axis=0).size().reset_index()
#Output:
     From        To  0
0  Kim YY    Ron AA  1
1  Kim YY  Smith JR  2
2  Ron AA  Smith JR  2
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Quick 'n Dirty

But not that dirty

```
pd.value_counts([*map(frozenset, zip(df.From, df.To))])

(Smith JR, Ron AA)    2
(Kim YY, Smith JR)    2
(Kim YY, Ron AA)      1
dtype: int64
```