# Dropping any row with identical cell values across columns

Tags: python, pandas

I couldn't find anything addressing this issue; [this is the closest I guess, but I can't figure out how to implement the ideas here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182228/python-delete-duplicates-in-a-dataframe-based-on-two-columns-combinations)

Somehow I found myself looking at a dataframe like this:

```
data = [['apple', 'banana','pear','mango'], ['pasta', 'pasta','pasta','pasta'], ['onion', 'tomato','celery','potato'], ['dog', 'dog','dog','dog']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

Which outputs:

```
        0   1         2     3
0   apple   banana  pear    mango
1   pasta   pasta   pasta   pasta
2   onion   tomato  celery  potato
3   dog     dog     dog     dog
```

The 2nd and 4th rows have identical values across all 4 columns and I would like to just get rid of them, so the final df looks like this:

```
        0   1         2     3
0   apple   banana  pear    mango
1   onion   tomato  celery  potato
```

Using `drop_duplicates()` doesn't do anything since there are no duplicate rows. Same with `duplicated()`.

The following is the only idea (if you can call it that) that I could think of. If I run

```
df.transpose()
```

I get

```
        0   1       2        3
0   apple   pasta   onion   dog
1   banana  pasta   tomato  dog
2   pear    pasta   celery  dog
3   mango   pasta   potato  dog
```

Now if I run `duplicated()` on, say, the 4th column:

```
df.duplicated(3)
```

I get

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

So maybe I can come up with a function that would transpose the df, run `duplicated()` on each column, drop the column if all values, except for the first, come back as `True` and then transpose the df back to its original shape.

But I don't know how to do that; also, I would intereseted to know if there is a more elegant way of getting to the same place.

Comment: you can use : `df[df.nunique(1)>1]`

Comment: @anky_91 - Wow, that was both fast and correct! Can you please explain, for those of us still straggling with pandas (preferably in an answer), how that accomplishes the task?

Comment: @rafaelc - You are right on both counts. `df.nunique` is more elegant, but in other situations the ability to test for `duplicated()` across columns may come handy!

Comment: as requested, i posted an answer with detailed explanation. I tried, Please let me know if something is unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) along `axis=1` and check for rows which has more than 1 unique value for all columns.:

Per docs: `nunique()`

> Count distinct observations over requested axis.

Hence if we test:

```
df.nunique(1)
```

This outputs:

```
0    4
1    1
2    4
3    1
```

Naturally

```
df.nunique(1)>1
```

Would return:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
```

so with help of [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) we can just do:

```
df[df.nunique(1)>1]
```

Which returns the desired output:

```
       0       1       2       3
0  apple  banana    pear   mango
2  onion  tomato  celery  potato
```